Does English have example of ou / u "alteration"?
I know that ou may go back to OE u: bound > bunden, found > funden
I know the only one example of ou / u "alteration" house but husband
Does English have other examples?

Does pronounce/pronunciation count?

And similarly announce →; denounce →; renounce →; enounce?

found(ation)/fund (same root); mouse/mustelid; slough/slough (different pronunciations), possibly coup (hit, obsolete except in dialect)/cuff (hit, etymology uncertain).
